# JSplitPane giving wrong resize cursor with GTK LAF?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, gtk

Running the official [`JSplitPane` demo](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) on my Ubuntu system gives a resize cursor like --> over the divider. The behavior of native split panes gives <--> resize cursors.
Does this qualify as a bug that should be reported to Sun (eh, Oracle)? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score -1):

This does not sound like a bug. The arrows at the top allow one click collapse/expansion of either side of the split pane. By these are by default turned off and the current look and feel of the application can also determine if one, both, or neither of the arrows are displayed. (This is also stated on in the URL you provided).

If you would like to enable one touch expansion:

```
mySplitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
```

If you did turn the one touch expandable on and it is not displaying, try changing the look and feel you are using.

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same thing. Split panes in Nautilus, for example, display the <--> resize cursor and are not one-touch expandable. I reported this to Sun along with some other Swing bugs but this was the only one not accepted. I guess it wasn't important enough for them :-\